# Issue with managing pointer to int array

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having some problem with my code, it crashes when I enter the value of `n`.

I have entered what I think the code should do.

I guess there is an issue with the pointer to `*a[i]` which cause the program to crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void assign_zero(int * a[], int * n){ // fetches value of a and n
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        *(a)[i] = 0; // puts every value in the array to 0 (a[3] = {0,0,0,0})
}

int main(){
    int n;

    printf("Choose value of n: ");
    scanf("%i", &n); // stores the int at n's adress
    int a[n]; // sets the length of the array

    assign_zero(&a, &n); // sends the adress of a and n to assign_zero

    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
    printf("%i", a[x]); // prints 00000... depending of n's value

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Crank up your compiler warnings. The first argument you feed to `assign_zero` is of the wrong type.

Comment: Why are you passing the addresses?

Comment: I am new to C but as I understand it I must pass the adress to change the variable in assign_zero since it's a void and wont return a value.

Comment: @DavidCarlsson Yes, but what you're passing is _already_ a pointer. You can't change the pointer itself, but you can change the content of the memory location it points to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your call, you're using

```
 assign_zero(&a, &n);
```

call. But the function signature is

```
void assign_zero(int * a[], int * n)
```

which seems wrong in this case. You only need a pointer, to hold the passed array, like

```
 void assign_zero(int * a, int * n)
```

will suffice. Then, in the function, you can directly use `a[i]` to access the elements of the array.

That said, it seems you're not modifying the value of `n` from `assign_zero()` function. If that is the case, you don't need to pass it as a pointer.

Comment: Thank you! How easy and clear it can be when someone shows you. Big ups to all of you!

Comment: Better late than never :)

Answer (score 2):

Too many `*`'s! Try this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void assign_zero(int * a, int n){ // fetches value of a and n
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = 0; // puts every value in the array to 0 (a[3] = {0,0,0})
}

int main(){
    int n;

    printf("Choose value of n: ");
    scanf("%i", &n); // stores the int at n's adress
    int a[n]; // sets the length of the array

    assign_zero(a, n); // sends the address of a and n to assign_zero

    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
    printf("%i", a[x]); // prints 00000... depending of n's value

    return 0;
}
```

You don't need to pass the address of `n` into `assign_zero` as you don't modify it within the function.

And any pointer is implicitly (and possibly dangerously) the base address of an array. That is to say you can index any pointer with square brackets, therefore you only need a to be declared a pointer to `int`.

Comment: Edited with more info

Comment: Because you can happily index a pointer out of bounds and good luck debugging the weird effects that can cause...

Comment: Oh that doesn't mean it's dangerous, only if you are not careful. Driving is dangerous too, but how often do you have an accident? And there are drivers that often have accidents because they are not careful. Or a chef might be dumb enough to cut his fingers every time he uses a knife, but if he is careful he will probably only have that accident once every 1000 times.

Comment: One of the definitions of dangerous is "likely to cause problems or to have adverse consequences" which is exactly what happens if you write into an array out of bounds and it doesn't outright crash.

Comment: Well yes, I wont argue to that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the addresses of the variables at all, if you redefine `assign_zero` like this

```
void assign_zero(int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = 0;
}
```

it would work fine if you call it like

```
printf("Choose value of n: ");
if (scanf("%i", &n) == 1) /* never ignore the return value of any function, NEVER */
{
    int a[n];
    assign_zero(a, n);

    for (int x = 0 ; x < n ; x++)
        printf("%i", a[x]);
}
```

but the `assign_zero` function is completely unnecessary, you can just

```
#include <string.h>
```

and then

```
memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
```

Comment: `int a[n] = {0};` What compiler allows this?  gcc complains that "variable-sized object may not be initialized"

Comment: @dbush Thanks, I  was not sure and didn't want to lookup the standard document, but I suspected that it was not possible. I never knew about VLA's until I started participating on Stack Overflow, when I needed one, I used `malloc()` and haven't yet started to work with them because the need hasn't appeared in the work I am doing now.